# Ttkbootstrap sets bootstyle to default

Tags: python, widget, ttkbootstrap

I'm having trouble applying the bootstyle for widgets in the ttkbootstrap module. The first time I run the code after restarting my IDE (Spyder), there seems to be no problem. Yet, the next times I run the code, my ttkbootstrap widgets have the default theme.

Here is my main.py code:

```
import ttkbootstrap as tb

root = tb.Window()

root.title("Test")
root.geometry('500x500')


#Label

myLabel = tb.Label(root, text = "Test2", font=("Helvetica",20),bootstyle = 'danger')


#Button
myButton = tb.Button(root, text = "Test3", bootstyle  = "danger")

myLabel.pack(pady = 50)
myButton.pack(pady = 20)
root.mainloop()
```

I've noticed there is zero information about this particular problem.

Comment: After a few more tries, i got the next warning in the console:

bgerror failed to handle background error.
Original error: can't invoke "event" command: application has been destroyed
Error in bgerror: can't invoke "tk" command: application has been destroyed

Comment: I would try out to use the atribute style = "danger.Inverse.TLabel" or style = "danger.TLabel"